# Can someone help me get my funds back in my possession from a contract?

Tags: transactions, tokens, contract-invocation, ethereum-wallet-dapp, sablier

So first off, buyer beware: do not mess around with gameswap.org it appears I made a mistake in doing so. Luckily I never invest more than I can stand to lose unless I really trust the project. So not too much is tied up in here but it's definitely an amount I'd put some effort in trying to get back to me.

If you take a look at the contract address for gameswap.org coin: GSWAP
https://etherscan.io/token/0xaac41EC512808d64625576EDdd580e7Ea40ef8B2

0xaac41EC512808d64625576EDdd580e7Ea40ef8B2 to search it yourself on etherscan.

You'll notice a bunch of "double" swap transfers that whenever someone unstakes their balancer pool tokens from the website a different function gets called and instead gets transfered to an account controlled by a Sablier Finance automated payout, so the second anything hits the account, it immediately gets transfered to another address. At first I thought I mightve been front runned, but after looking through a few transactions I noticed it looks like this person set it up purposefully as a scam.

Is there anyway I can interact with the contract to unstake or withdrawal my LP tokens and make sure it goes back into my possession? It looks like when I tried to unstake from the site it called Function: noRewardsWithdraw(uint256 _pid) you can see from my original transaction:

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x96e641e447080e3c3b54553ddda87c946343f93995209f26a5f3a054b1c3385e

Manual txn lookup:
0x96e641e447080e3c3b54553ddda87c946343f93995209f26a5f3a054b1c3385e

Let me know if I need to add more info, thank you in advance for any insight and knowledge of blockchain usage that I gain from this and hopefully my funds as well.

Comment: After a quick read of the contract it seems the tokens were sent to the sablier payroll (0xbd6a40Bb904aEa5a49c59050B5395f7484A4203d), there the employee seems can withdraw by calling withdrawFromStream on the payroll contract, but I have no idea what parameters have to be send. Or I might be totally wrong.

Comment: No, you're correct in that part, but that's the obvious part, I already mentioned in the post. Sablier.finance is a blockchain app used to payout crypto at the users desired interval. For all intensive purposes the most practical one is instant withdrawal any time Balance >= 0. So the second anything hits the address, it's immediately sent to another address without having human interaction checking every so often. But I can't figure out if there is a way that I can call a different function that allows me to bypass whatever call he is making when I manually click "Claim LP" on the website.

Comment: I can only check the contract I don't know what the website does. The sablier system move funds to other contracts, but they can be withdrawby calling withdrawFromStream from the payroll contract by the recipient.

Comment: It's a normal DeFi website where you stake your LP to farm a coin. The issue is when I go to unstake the LP tokens that I own, and originally staked, the LP tokens get sent to that guy instead of, rightfully being returned to me(the actual, true original owner of the LP tokens). I hope that helps make sense of things. MY LP tokens, get sent to some person instead of being returned to me.

Comment: Hey @Legionz that other "person" is the Sablier protocol. You have not been scammed. Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Co-founder of Sablier here. You have not been scammed, the "immediate transfer" you're talking about is just how the protocol works (Sablier V1 transfers the tokens from one contract to another one).

GSWAP is using Sablier to stream the LP tokens to you - think of this like vesting shares but in DeFi fashion. Our [docs](https://docs.sablier.com/concepts/protocol/streaming) explain what money streaming is.

You can head to [v1-app.sablier.com](https://v1-app.sablier.com) and log in with your MetaMask wallet to claim the BPT tokens (for V2, check out [app.sablier.com](https://app.sablier.com)).